# JavaScript codewars task

Tags: javascript

For the past few hours I have been trying to solve one of the CodeWars challenge - but without any luck - so that is the Task -

https://www.codewars.com/kata/554ca54ffa7d91b236000023/train/javascript - link to the task

Task

Given a list lst and a number N, create a new list that contains each number of lst at most N times without reordering. For example if N = 2, and the input is [1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3], you take [1,2,3,1,2], drop the next [1,2] since this would lead to 1 and 2 being in the result 3 times, and then take 3, which leads to [1,2,3,1,2,3].

and that is an example --

Example

deleteNth ([1,1,1,1],2) // return [1,1]

deleteNth ([20,37,20,21],1) // return [20,37,21]

```
function deleteNth(arr,x){

  for (var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
  for(var j = i+1; j<arr.length; j++){
  var crr = 1;
  if(arr[i]===arr[j])
  crr =+ 1;
  while(crr>=x){
    arr.splice(arr[j], 1);
  crr--;
  }
  }
  return arr;
}
```

That is my code and idea - As I am a beginner in JS can you give me suggestions and tell me if my idea is good or not. Also I know that i have made some mistakes - so if possible - point them out

Comment: What's the name of that task on codewars? Or just post the link so I can read the description and understand it more clearly.

Comment: https://www.codewars.com/kata/554ca54ffa7d91b236000023/train/javascript

Answer (score 1):

`totals` object will keep a counter for each value of the array.

```js
function deleteNth(arr, x) {
  let totals = {};
  return arr.filter(o => (totals[o] = ++totals[o] || 0) < x);
}

console.log(deleteNth([1, 1, 1, 1], 2));
console.log(deleteNth([20, 37, 20, 21], 1));
```

Comment: Thank you very much! And by the way - do you think my idea is feasible and are there any mistakes in my code?

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach will be:

```js
const deleteNth = (lst, N) => {
  const res = [];
  const countNums = {};

  lst.forEach((el, idx) => {
    countNums[el] = countNums[el] ? countNums[el] + 1 : 1;
    if(countNums[el] <= N) {
      res.push(el);
    }
  })

  return res;
}

console.log(deleteNth([1,2,1, 3,1,2,3,3, 5], 2))
result => [ 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 5 ]
```